# iOS Today View extension doesn't respect accessibility settings

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, accessibility, ios-app-today-view

I use iOS's accessibility settings to change text size - I'm young and I have good eyes so I make the text a couple clicks smaller than usual. It helps get more on the page.

The iOS app Today View extension doesn't seem to respect this:

[image]

Notice how the system text at the top of the screenshot is adjusted, and the HNQ text isn't.

Could the text in the extension auto-size to my preferences like everything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been implemented! The change will become available in Beta version 1.2.2.185.